# R Split one column in a df into different columns based on length

Tags: r, tidyverse, stringr

I have a data frame with a column containing text data.
I want to SPLIT that one column into many columns based on length.
Like say, the column has text that says, "I need more data today," I want to split it such that the max every split column has is five long.
So, in this case, the total length is 22. I need the first 5 in col1, the next 5 in col2, the next 5 in col3, and so.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one possible way using `strsplit` to split at every `n` characters (here, five) into a list, `do.call` to `rbind` the list elements, and `lapply` to get the max lengths for the number of columns:

Example data:

```
txt <- c("I need more data today", "I need", "I", "I need more data")
```

Code

```
n <- 5
splttxt <- strsplit(txt, 
                    paste0("(?<=", paste(rep(".", times = n), 
                                         collapse = ""), ")"),
                    perl = TRUE)
finaltxt <- do.call(rbind, lapply(lapply(splttxt, unlist), 
                                          `length<-`, max(lengths(splttxt))))
colnames(finaltxt) <- paste0("col", 1:ncol(finaltxt))
```

Output:

```
#      col1    col2    col3    col4    col5
# [1,] "I nee" "d mor" "e dat" "a tod" "ay"
# [2,] "I nee" "d"     NA      NA      NA  
# [3,] "I"     NA      NA      NA      NA  
# [4,] "I nee" "d mor" "e dat" "a"     NA
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `read.fwf`: A function to read fixed widths:

```
n <- 5
mx <- max(nchar(txt))
read.fwf(textConnection(txt),c(rep(n, mx%/%n), mx%%n))

    V1    V2    V3    V4   V5
1 I nee d mor e dat a tod   ay
2 I nee     d  <NA>  <NA> <NA>
3     I  <NA>  <NA>  <NA> <NA>
4 I nee d mor e dat     a <NA>
```